# How to change json value containing hyphens in Java?

Tags: java, json

Here is my json file

```
    {
  "file-list":[
    "ab3bdc2c3d-f2fg63-42c3-abasd53-e78c66afc77d"
  ],
  "metadata":{
    "X-Object-Meta-Favourite":"true"
  }
}
```

So i want to change `"X-Object-Meta-Favourite":"true"` 's value to false.

First i read

```
public static JSONObject favourite() throws IOException {

    String body = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/test/resources/config/environments/FileSystem/Favourite.json")));
        return new JSONObject(body);
    
    }
```

And it returns JSONObject. So i use this body int his method:

```
public void fovurite(String action) throws IOException {

    action = "false";

    JSONObject body = readFiles.favourite();
    body.put(body.getJSONObject("metadata").getString("X-Object-Meta-Favourite"),action);
```

But added `true = "false"` value. I couldnt change `X-Object-Meta-Favourite` ' value.

I also tried `body.put("metadata['X-Object-Meta-Favourite']",action)` but this time added `metadata['X-Object-Meta-Favourite'] = "false"`

In short how can i change this value ? Thank you for your advice

Comment: From what library is `JSONObject`? Add a mention and a tag.

Comment: From a question quality perspective, the fact that the JSON keys contain hyphens is totally incidental to the actual problem. I think the title needs to be reworded, but I’m not sure how to summarise this clearly. Maybe it should be closed as “caused by a typo?”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
body.put(body.getJSONObject("metadata").getString("X-Object-Meta-Favourite"),action);
```

Used this one

```
body.getJSONObject("metadata").put("X-Object-Meta-Favourite", action);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the value of the X-Object-Meta-Favourite and putting action in a field of said value, so basically you are putting "false" inside a field named "true", what you want to do is to get the nested object, modify it and put it in a field named metadata.

so it wold be something like:

```
JSONObject body = readFiles.favourite();
JSONObject nested = body.getJSONObject("metadata");
nested.put("X-Object-Meta-Favourite", action);
body.put("metadata", nested);
```

I have not tested the code but I hope you understand what I mean.